# Export data from PoseNet app by tensorflow-lite in android

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to export data from the app PoseNet by tensorflow in android to Excel sheet, Currently without success. I would be glad for help from your experience if this is possible and if so how to do it?
tnx!

Comment: What data are you trying to export? Please include it.

Comment: the data type that im want to export is the coordinates x and y of the body part which the app follows them, by time